# how to fetch selected value in select2 in edit form

Tags: php

I am currently working in codeigniter(PHP).
I create one form which includes select2 control.and inserted value of select2 control in database successfully.
Now I want to fetch value of particular inserted value in select2 control when edit the form.
My selected select value is store in one variable Now i want that value dispaly in select2 control when edit form is open.

Comment: please show the code you've got and where you got stuck!

Comment: Show your code?

Comment: Please add the related code to your question, so that debugging can be easier. In this way the question is going too broad.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you just need to put value and trigger change event to make changes in select2. As given in below example.

```js
$("#mychooice").select2();
changeVal2();
function changeVal1(){
  $("#mychooice").val("bbb").change();
}

function changeVal2(){
  $("#mychooice").val("ccc").change();
}
```

```css
#mychooice{
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.js"></script>
<select id="mychooice" palceholder="Your Choice">
<option>aaa</option>
<option>bbb</option>
<option>ccc</option>
</select>

<button onclick="changeVal1()" type="button">Change Value to 'bbb' </button>

<button onclick="changeVal2()" type="button">Change Value to 'ccc' </button>
```